# How to correctly convert MySQL invalid DATE into EF Core model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

There's some invalid MySQL `DATE` data in the record: "2017-00-00"

I can't modify this database, so I am trying to convert it in `OnModelCreating`, using `HasConversion` method like this:

```cs
entity
    .Property(e => e.Launchdt)
    .HasConversion(
        new ValueConverter<DateTime,String>(
            convertToProviderExpression: v => v.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            convertFromProviderExpression: v => v switch
            {
                null => DateTime.MinValue,
                _    => Regex.IsMatch(v, @"\d{4}-00-00") ?
                            DateTime.ParseExact($"{Regex.Match(v, @"(\d{4})-00-00").Groups[1].Value}-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd",  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ) :
                            DateTime.ParseExact(v, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            }
        )
    );
```

But it could not be compiled because of the switch statement in the expression.

```
[CS8514] 식 트리에는 switch 식이 포함될 수 없습니다.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

The problem table's DDL (I cannot paste original version of DDL)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `error_table` (
  `goodsno` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  --
  -- ...
  --
  `launchdt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  --
  -- ...
  --
  PRIMARY KEY (`goodsno`),
  --
  -- ...
  --
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=/* FORBIDDEN */ DEFAULT CHARSET=euckr
```

launchdt column is the problem.

---

I changed connection string to not use ConvertZeroDatetime, and to use AllowZeroDatetime.

At this point, the problem above is solved but another exception has thrown,

```cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlConversionException: Cannot convert MySqlDateTime to DateTime when IsValidDateTime is false.
```

Now I'm finding a way to solve this.

Comment: Dates will never contain `00-00` for `MM-dd`.

Comment: By not using `switch` expressions? You can rewrite this as a simple series of `? :` expressions (`v is null ? DateTime.MinValue : Regex.IsMatch(...`). No guarantee that it works then, of course, but that at least avoids the plain error of the lambda.

Comment: ...all of this is use of `HasConversion` completely unnecessary: EF Core can use `date`-typed columns directly, either with `DateTime` or `DateOnly`-typed object properties. If your table is using a string/text type to store dates then that is incorrect and you should fix that first.

Comment: @Dai YES. But this DB contains it. And I can't edit this DB. So I have to conversion it. And also, MySQL doesn't validate DATE or DATETIME, so these weird values are still there in DB.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried it and it seems working, but I am seeing another runtime error so if I solve this, I will try it again correctly and comment it. Thanks.

Comment: @Dai DB is using DATE format of that column. But, as the question, the value of column is 2017-00-00 so it could not convert it correctly, throws not valid date error

Comment: @Honsal Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the table.

Comment: @Dai I edited the post.

However, I tried to track what is wrong with it, and found the fact like this.

the `MySqlDataReader.GetDateOnly` internally calls `DateOnly.FromDateTime(GetDateTime(ordinal))`.

So even I have made the type of model's property to `DateOnly?` already, MySQL is tried to convert it `DateTime` first, then `DateOnly`.

The problem is occurring `MySqlDataReqder.GetDateTime`, when calling `DateTime..ctor`

Comment: If you disable `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` then the `date` column will work correctly.

Comment: @Dai As I understand, you are saying change DB mode. I can't do this because owner doesn't want any changes of DB.
That's why I am finding a way to solve this problem with C#

Comment: In that case, I think your best option is to tell you boss that the database, as-is, **is broken** and it needs to be repaired (by correcting invalid-dates and disabling the `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` option) - otherwise your work will take 10x as long to complete - see how they feel about that.

Comment: As I am freelance, it is hard to talk. But I will talk him to this problem anyway. I will be back after some conversation.

However, I feel like I am getting close to the answer. If you have some time, please see my edit.

Comment: Oh, it was not. IsValidDatetime cannot be changed by connection string or something like that. It is hardcoded by comparing `Year != 0 && Month != 0 && Day != 0;` of `MySqlDateTime`. Now I am going to call with owner.

Comment: @Dai Owner confirmed modification of DB. But this DB is accepting so many data in a time, so I have to modify PHP code(~15 yrs old) too. Sad, but at least this problem is solved.

Comment: @Honsal 